# How to access rendered html in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, dom, web-inspector

We know that JavaScript and JQuery codes can add some elements to HTML on runtime.

and for that reason in some case (firefox: View page source) is different by (firefox: Web developer Inspector)

In PHP when we get a webpage by `file_get_contents` we access html code(like firefox view page source)

But I want to save fully rendered html in PHP exactly same code that we can see in (firefox: web developer Inspector)

How can I do it?

Comment: you can't do it in PHP alone - for a start, PHP has no DOM or javascript engine

Comment: You could use some headless browser like phantomjs to generate the rendered html code and then save `document.body.innerHTML`.